# How can I run code in Eclipse IDE using keyboard shortcut keys

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm very much new to Eclipse IDE and running a code over and over (like when debugging a program) is somehow became a nuisance specially when I'm rushing a code.

Any ideas on how can I run my code without pretty much clicking everywhere?

Thanks!!

Comment: See: https://www.eclipse.org/getting_started/content/eclipse-ide-keybindings.pdf

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on Windows to run without Debugging. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> on Mac. <kbd>F11</kbd> to run with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to go to "Window->Preferences->Keys" and explore that dialog. You can filter for particular strings and you can sort by bindings.  Get familiar with what you see there.  That dialog also allows you to change bindings, but I wouldn't do that until you think you know what you're doing.

I should point out that the Emacs+ Eclipse plugin gives you better visibility into bindings.  Using that, you can quickly check bindings from different perspectives, without opening the preferences dialog.